# WPF application won't open using Application.Run();

Tags: c#, wpf

I have referenced System.Windows.Forms.dll, and want to use `Application.Run();` but my application won't open. I don't get any errors in the console, and the application is visible in Task Manager.

This is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TextBoxOutputter outputter;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        outputter = new TextBoxOutputter(TestBox);
        Console.SetOut(outputter);


        using (var api = new KeystrokeAPI())
        {
            api.CreateKeyboardHook((character) => { Console.Write(character); });
            Application.Run();
        }

    }
}
```

Without `Application.Run();` the application does run but crashes immediately after pressing any key. I get this message when it crashes:

> CallbackOnCollectedDelegate' : 'A callback was made on a garbage
>   collected delegate of type
>   'KeystrokeAPI!Keystroke.API.User32+LowLevelHook::Invoke'. This may
>   cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing
>   delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed
>   application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.'

I am using this API: https://github.com/fabriciorissetto/KeystrokeAPI

Comment: show the entry point of the application and where you create the `MainWindow`, it seems you might be doing something a little strange and maybe calling Run twice or something, which doesn't exactly explain the error though...

Comment: It is at the top of `public partial class MainWindow : Window {`

Comment: Why are calling Application.Run from within a window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WPF application, which I assume is yours, will call `Application.Run();` from the application's entry point. You should be able to set the hook in your application before you run it then set the Console output when your Window loads.

`App.xaml`;
Remove the StartupUri tag and replace it with Startup, creating a new event callback in `App.xaml.cs`.

`App.xaml.cs`
Inside the new startup event callback, you can set the hook.

```
using (var api = new KeystrokeAPI())
        {
            api.CreateKeyboardHook((character) => { Console.Write(character); });
            Application.Run();
        }
```

`MainWindow.cs` Then, once your window has loaded, you should be able to Console's output.

```
public void Init()
    {
        outputter = new TextBoxOutputter(TestBox);
        Console.SetOut(outputter);
    }
```

This means you do not call `Application.Run();` twice whilst hook is still made.

Currently, I believe the problem is, you launch the app, which automatically initializes a new instance and runs it. You then, also call `Application.Run();` which now overrides previous initialization and starts again. This means your Window, Console & Delegate are now in a previous, overridden instance, and destroyed by GC. Thus, you have bound the KeystrokeAPI to a delegate - `(character) => { Console.Write(character); }` - which has been destroyed.